# looping through a number of searched for columns and filling values

Tags: vba, excel

so ive got this vba to filter for blanks and fill a column red based on values <4. i now want to filter on 3 additional columns which i need to search the workbook and fill values of less than for red, so declare 3 more ranges

```
Sub test()
  Dim SearchCol As String
  Dim rng1 As Range
  Dim rng2 As Range
  Dim ws As Worksheet

SearchCol = "ID"

For Each ws In Worksheets
    Set rng1 = ws.UsedRange.Find(SearchCol, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    Set rng2 = ws.UsedRange.Find("Amount", , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        With ws
            .Range("A2").AutoFilter field:=rng1.Column, Criteria1:="<>"
            .Range("A2").AutoFilter field:=rng2.Column, Criteria1:="<4"
            On Error Resume Next
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, rng2.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range(.Cells(rng2.Row + 1, rng2.Column), .Cells(lastRow, rng2.Column)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand what you need. Can you explain please in details?

Comment: so i want to do everything as above but also filter for 3 more columns for values of <4, id need to search for these columns and loop it through all the sheets

Comment: Are u looking for a macro to fill the color if the value is less than < 4 in some specific columns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you need?

```
Sub test()
    Dim col1Name As String, colName(2 To 5) As String
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng(2 To 5) As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    Dim restrictions(2 To 5) As String


    On Error Resume Next

    col1Name = "ID"
    colName(2) = "Amount"
    colName(3) = "test1"
    colName(4) = "test2"
    colName(5) = "test3"

    restrictions(2) = "<4"
    restrictions(3) = "<4"
    restrictions(4) = "<4"
    restrictions(5) = "<4"

    For Each ws In Worksheets

        With ws

            For i = 2 To 5
                ws.AutoFilterMode = False
                Set rng1 = .UsedRange.Find(col1Name, , xlValues, xlWhole)
                Set rng(i) = .UsedRange.Find(colName(i), , xlValues, xlWhole)

                If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then .Range("A2").AutoFilter field:=rng1.Column, Criteria1:="<>"
                If Not rng(i) Is Nothing Then
                    .Range("A2").AutoFilter field:=rng(i).Column, Criteria1:=restrictions(i)
                    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, rng(i).Column).End(xlUp).Row
                    .Range(.Cells(rng(i).Row + 1, rng(i).Column), .Cells(lastrow, rng(i).Column).Address).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                End If
            Next i

        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: in what line have you got it?

Comment: lastRow = variable not defined

Comment: bram91  - add this line at the beginning of ur module >> Dim lastRow as integer

Comment: that solves it but it only fills col2 red not the others

Comment: are you want to fill with color only columns from rng1,rng2,..,rng5, or entire row?

Comment: that fills the id column which i dont want

Comment: only the col 2 to 5 i want to fill col 1 just filtering out blanks

Comment: this seems to highlight everything on that row for the range and column, i want it to highlight by column, id also like it to work for when i change the criteria1:=

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. It highlights for me col2, col3,col4,col5 when col1<>"" and col2<4,...,col5<4. Isn't it what you want?

Comment: it hasnt highlighted all the values of <4 for me and for example col1=10 so not highlighted but on the same row col3=2 and isnt highlighted

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45810/discussion-between-simoco-and-bram91)